# How do I used vscode to call android emulator and fix Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'?

Tags: android, flutter, macos, visual-studio-code

How do I used vscode to call android emulator?

I can call iPhone13 & web, but when I used without debugging way, it wasn't call android emulator. I tried to add android it's show me `avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK`

Where has problems? I'd added android studio and create AVD emulator.

Because I tried to used flutter to development, so I needs use android, iPhone and web.

How can fix it?

I sloved the problem, but I got new issue, how do I fix it?

`What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.`

Comment: run flutter doctor and see is there anything missing !!

Comment: @Loop_assembly Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.

Comment: @Loop_assembly I can call android emulator, but I've new issue, `What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

`

Answer (score 0):

On the top menu vscode:

Go to `View` -> `Command Palette` -> type `Flutter: Launch Emulator` and chosse it -> select an emulator to launch

Comment: I tried do it before, but it was show to me avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK when I click create android emulator

Comment: I updated my content.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna call iPhoneEmulator must have Xcode fist

install iphoneSdk via Xcode

in Vscode you can call emulator via Terminal in Vscode

"flutter run" then select device you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I updated my content.